# Is it legal for a company to continue using my name and picture on their site, despite not being an employee anymore?

Tags: united-states, employment

A few months ago I decided to leave a company whose CEO engaged in a lot of questionable practices. ([1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/100750/how-to-convince-ceo-that-giving-real-projects-to-candidates-is-a-terrible-idea), [2](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23883/is-it-illegal-to-continue-using-oauth-tokens-after-a-user-asks-to-remove-them))

It has come to my attention that this CEO is using my name, title, picture and current company on the company's page as a "Testimonial"

He's also still using my name, picture, and e-mail address to deceive leads and customers into thinking that they have access to the "technical lead" of the platform itself.

I have texted, e-mailed and called him multiple times asking him to take down my picture, my name and my testimonial from the page. I have also asked him to stop impersonating me. He hasn't replied.

Is there anything I can do to force him to stop? I don't care if I burn a bridge with him. It's not a bridge worth keeping. I'm concerned about my reputation and my supervisors might think that I'm still associated with my former company. Can an individual issue a Cease and Desist letter?

I am in the US if that matters.

Comment: Did you ever previously sign a release form that many orgs use when they post pics of people online?

Comment: no I didn't sign such a thing.